# loadeddata and other events didn't get fired upon calling load() on <video> tag in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, html5-video, microsoft-edge

I have recently observed a strange situation involving IE/Edge browsers and events associated with media resource tags like `<video>`, `<audio>` etc.

On the [html5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#dom-htmlmediaelement-load) and several reputable sites like MDN I learnt that `load()` function called on a resource object like video has to cause firing of a set of events like `loadstart`, `loadeddata` etc. At first glance it seems to be an old feature supported everywhere down to IE9. But in reality it actually doesn't happen in Microsoft's browsers.

What am I trying to do? There is a hidden `<video>` tag on the page. Basically a user clicks on a control element on the page and I show a loader waiting for the data (first frame) to come. Once the page receives the data - start playing the video. I catch `loadeddata` event in order to hide loader and show&play actual `<video>`. However, whatever I do in IE/Edge - calling `load()` or dynamically set `src` for `<video>` - it has no effect. The `readyState` property of `<video>` remains 0 meaning it didn't even start to load the data. I am pretty sure the video isn't in the cache but for completeness sake I tried to bust the cache by adding random string to video's url. No effect. **However**, if I directly just call `play()` on `<video>` it actually starts doing the job and fires all the events finally making the video play.

Why didn't corresponding events get fired upon calling `load()` on `<video>` tag in IE/Edge?

Comment: You said your video tag is hidden. It can be a possible reason that events are not firing. Try to make a test with a visible video element to see the results. You did not post the sample code so I am not sure about your exact code. For testing purposes, try to put console.log in each event. so that we can verify until which event it worked and where it gets stopped. I found in some docs that load() will only execute if the data is loaded completely. It can be possible that your data is not loaded completely and you are calling load().

Comment: Try to make a test with HTMLMediaElement: emptied event. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/emptied_event This is also a helpful article. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/

Comment: I couldn't clarify the issue and ended up just detecting whether it is a miscrosoft browser and if so, call `play()`...

Comment: Thanks for informing us about the workaround for your issue.